# How to pass a list/menu value as a class to an element?

Tags: jquery, forms, list, parameter-passing

I have a dropdown list/menu and each option has a value. I would like that value to be passed to an element to determine the desired styling. Here is my raw html, hoping jquery is capable of doing this. The element that it needs to be passed too is called

```
 <div class="user-text">
```

So am hoping it can add a class like this per the value.

```
 <div class="user-text curveMeTop">
```

Here is my list with the values

```
 <div class="top15">
  <div class="label">Text Warp</div>
  <select name="warp-list">
    <option value="curveMeTop">Curve Top</option>
    <option value="curveMeBottom">Curve Bottom</option>
    <option value="wave">Wave</option>
    <option value="buldge">Buldge</option>
    <option value="skew">Skew</option>
  </select>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$(function(){
    $('#warp-list').on('change', function() {
        $('div.user-text').attr('class', 'user-text ' + $(this).find('option:selected').val());
    });
});
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpSh2/) for example.

The reason why I'm setting the class via [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) rather than addClass is otherwise you would keep adding additional classes each time you changed the drop-down selection. The alternative is trying to remove each and every class option first, or reset the class to nothing and then add in the 'user-text' class and also the class that you want added.

Comment: off topic perhaps, but why use on() instead of change()

Comment: "The new .on() and .off() APIs unify all the ways of attaching events to a document in jQuery — and they’re shorter to type!" See http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/ for more info. In short, it's the newer **preferred** way of doing events.

Comment: Thanks, I really like how you thought ahead on that, it had not occurred to me that would happen. Unfortunately I tried your code and its not working for me. I even tried replacing the 'select" with an id I assigned to the dropdown.                                                                                                                                   $('#warp-list').on('change', function() {
    $('div.user-text').attr('class', 'user-text ' +      $(this).find('option:selected').val());
});

Comment: It's working in jsfiddle land, so there's obviously something else in your code that is stopping it. Can you post more code?

Comment: Here is what I have so far. http://neocenturymedia.com/external_files/logo/demo.html Many Thanks Blair!!

Comment: `$('div.user-text')` doesn't return anything. What part of that page are you trying to change?

Comment: via the dropdown list, I'd like to add the option value to the div.user-text. So if someone selects buldge from the dropdown., it looks like this   <div class="user-text buldge">  Im not really sure what you mean by doesnt return anything. I need to ramp up my skills.  btw, thanks for turning me on to jsfiddle, that looks like a really handy site!!

Comment: The problem is that `<div class="user-text">` doesn't exist on the page. So the javascript is trying to add a class to something that doesn't exist. Are you trying to adjust the class of the textarea that says "Type some text in here to be appended" or something else?

Comment: ahhh, now I see what you mean. That class inst there until you type something in the box, and hit the button "insert your own text" this puts that div in the dom <div class="user-text">my text</div>

Comment: The other problem that you have is that you don't have the javascript running when the DOM is ready (do a quick google search to read up on DOM ready and why it's important). I'll update my answer with what you need.

Comment: wow, so whenever Im looking at something post page load I use $(document).ready(function() rather than $(function() that is really cool. Thanks so much Blair!! I am thrilled to have learned that!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `addClass` method::

```
$('select').change(function(){
  var cls = $(this).val();
  $('.user-text').addClass(cls);
})
```